# Android app to send a text message with only one tap

Tags: android, sms

I would like to send a text or emoticon to other person with the lowest number of taps, ideally only one. A widget with predefined text to a predefined person would be enough.

Is there any app capable to do this?

Comment: you can just use tasker and set up a task to send the predefined text. and add a task shortcut on your homescreen.

Answer (score 2):

#### [Emergency button](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.emergency.button)

While not the intended use-case, it fits the criteria in your question. Using this app, you first define the phone number and message, then you can send that message using the widget. It requires two taps instead of one in order to reduce the probability of unintentional triggering. It also has the option to send an email and share your GPS location.

[image][image]

Comment: Seems needs more than one tap since after pressing the widget button, app opens and asks for confirmation. Do you know if I can disable this confirmation?

Comment: @biotech Unfortunately, it appears that they have changed it in their last update without updating their screenshots as well. Now the widget only has one button and a confirmation message. Maybe the developers would add the option if you email them about it. Their contact info in on the play store page. Another option is to tweak the code yourself, since it's open-source